# Unable to open .RPT file in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have installed Visual Studio 2010,it doesn't include crystal Reports, so I downloaded SAP Crystal Report externally from MSDN and installed SAP Crystal Reports.

When I open Visual Studio 2010 I am unable to design existing .RPT files, but when I run an application existing Reports opens.

So what can be the reason why I can't design .rpt files?

Comment: How could anyone possibly answer that question with so little information?

Comment: What do you mean by "the .rpt file does not open"? Are you trying to open it by double-clicking the icon file? It won't work. Did you create the RPT file with VS2010 or with andother Crystal Reports version? If you created it with CR it won't open.

Comment: it opens perfactly with digital numbers. but unable to design and modify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to install Crystal Reports For Visual Studio 2010 on your developer machine as well as Runtime Engine.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two versions of Crystal Reports provided :

- Crystal Reports Redistribution Version.

- Crystal Reports For Visual Studio.

Be sure that you have downloaded the right one.
If the problem insists try to uninstall CR and clean registry and all stuff and then re-install again.
Hope it helps